# jQuery Development with Bootstrap template

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I bought a responsive admin panel template built with bootstrap. I have a question:

What is the best way of using tools to implement jquery calls to a webservice to update stats and the rest of functions on the page. I also used to it in notepad++ but I need more efficient tools for developing javascript and adding it to the .html files of the admin panel.

Comment: What is wrong with notepad++?  What kind of functionality are you specifically looking for?

Comment: Search on google, you will get 1000's from it.

Comment: @BradleyTrager nothing is wrong with it, but i am looking for something that makes writing code more easy by predicting function names, syntax error check etc..

Comment: @RohanKumar I already did. Now i am asking here :)

Comment: For predicting function names, error checking etc, you are probably looking for WebStorm.  I personally use sublime text 3.

Answer (score 1):

if you can pay for license then [webstrom](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) is best.

I am from java background therefore I use eclipse ide

Answer (score 1):

The tool you use is your own choice. Some people will feel better on notepad++, other better with Sublime Text,...

You have to try them to make your own opinion and choose the one you feel most confortable with.

The code predictor you're talking about is called intellisense.

Take a look at this question. It seems to be quiet similar as your question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925219/best-javascript-editor-or-ide-with-intellisense-and-debugging-possibly